# Is it possible to build a home automation system with web technology?

Tags: javascript, php, coldfusion

I can build all sorts of web applications with common web technologies on both the client and server (JavaScript, PHP, CFML, etc.).

I would like to build some home automation tools and I have no idea how to get from the strictly digital world to the physical world.

Let's say I want a super simple web app to display a bunch of switches in the user interface for some different things in my house. Let's say I'm using X10 hardware (http://www.x10.com/x10-basics.html) that is "listening" for some radio signal.

Is there a way to use web technology to "instruct" my devices (smartphone, tablet, laptop, whatever) to "broadcast signals" to these X10 (or any) physical device in order to make my home more Jetsons-like?

It seems like JavaScript couldn't do any of this because of security stuff, but perhaps a server app running on my local device on my home network could tie into some underlying OS library and do this?

```
wirelessService = new system.os.superCoolWirelessBroadcasterService();

wirelessService.broadcastSignal("6520 mghz", true); // toaster frequency
```

Comment: theoretically possible, but unless your phone has a software-defined radio in it (or attached to it), you can't just start broadcasting arbitrary signals.

Comment: Check out raspberry pi... There's a ton of insane things you can do with those.

Comment: you can send a request to your server from a website in a browser, then you have to setup arduino controllers for electronics, and your server can communicate with the arduino's based on the request body / data.

Comment: Do a google search for "X10 USB"

Comment: @shredmill raspberry pi is a good entry-level server, and probably your best option for intermittent requests like switching lights on, turning the oven off etc.. but the main part is adding the interactivity on the home appliances, thats the hard part.

Comment: Yes. I would build this web app on a VPS on the internet, and then have a Raspberry Pi request updates periodically on an authenticated pull basis (e.g. every 10 minutes). That means that you don't need to worry about the uptime of the Pi, which may not be ideal, and you don't need to poke incoming holes into your home firewall. I don't think you need radio signals for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All my mobile stuff is an HTML5 front end with an self-hosting asp.net web API backend. I use a https proxy application for security.  But I run my stuff on an intranet. It's very easy in my opinion and very rewarding.

Here are a couple of videos:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_2_JSbEytnM
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zOhOEWoED4M

Now I did integrate Google Glass which is an app:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vLmPJ9xvfs0

Here you can find a complete listing:

https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=nick+tullos+home+automation

Here is some of the source code:

https://github.com/NickTullos/CrestJson

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You absolutely can.  I created several automated processes with Coldfusion.  Look at the scheduled tasks section of the Coldfusion administrator.

Many things that are one of specialized tools like barcodes generation or scanner software (just as examples) have third party dlls on Windows with Coldfusion (nothing is perfect mind you) some even required us to extend Internet Explorer via activeX controls.  Some of these things included warehousing housekeeping tools, three dimensional boxing interfacing, shipped product checks and payment authorization switches, refund switches, warehousing scale interfaces and U.S. Mail/Endicia/UPS manifest generation.

Nowadays, I do many automated import processes with third party source data. Just formatted CSV or Excel files sent via FTP where I scan and pick of the file for processing.

We also parse raw data from a power inverter and create graphs for review and other statistically useful things for a client. This was not an easy task because there are things in that technology that I am not equipped for and had to learn (power inverter speak). Also the shorthand their technologists used to name data-points made some sense to them, but was immensely obscure and not very easy to translate.

I will tell you that one of the hardest interfaces I worked with was a 1996 serial port based warehouse scale that we got after the DHL bankruptcy.  I thought I would lose my mind.  There were baud settings like older modems and if there was a failure it didn't do anything (no error nothing).

I would assume you would have to consider that obscure real world interfacing with things that are digital may or may not be feasible.

Coldfusion is very good at automating because it is a dynamic language with an easy to use administrative backend that can access deeper things via Java objects and native .NET support (so anything is possible)!

Comment: Yea...I don't think he is talking about the same 'automation' as you are.

Comment: Are you sure?  It sounds to me like he's describing controlling *hardware* with a high level programming language by leveraging low-level interface libraries.  That pretty much sounds like what the OP is asking for.